# WPGraphQl Yoast SEO Plugin for GatsbyJS build

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, yoast

I am trying to create a SEO component for all of my posts in my GatsbyJS build. The site is built with `gatsby-source-graphql` as well as `WPGraphQL WordPress plugin` on my WP installation. For my SEO component am I trying to use `WPGraphQl Yoast SEO Plugin`.

I am querying meta description etc. in a [fragment](https://github.com/TurboTobiasDK/bp/blob/master/src/templates/post/data.js) and then passing this information in a React helmet using an [SEO component](https://github.com/TurboTobiasDK/bp/blob/master/src/templates/post/index.js).

This kinda works and is querying the metadescription when I console.log. My problem is now that it will only return metaDesc for the first post and is, therefore, passing the same metaDesc to all of my posts.

If I pass in a filter it will display the correct metadescription:

```
query MyQuery {
  wpgraphql {
    posts(where: {id: 608}) {
      edges {
        node {
          seo {
            metaDesc
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

During createPosts I figured I needed to add some kind of dynamic filter that would only query for specific ID so I tried the following:

```
query MyQuery {
  wpgraphql {
    posts(where: {id: ${id}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          seo {
            metaDesc
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this solution is giving me an error: `String interpolations are not allowed in graphql fragments.`. I am therefore looking for a solution on how I could pass in the right metaDescription for each individual posts instead of the current situation where it will only pass metaDesc of the first post.

You can find my repo [here](https://github.com/TurboTobiasDK/bp)

Comment: why use any filter when you want to fetch all posts?

Comment: guess I figured that the filter would be passed dynamically to each post while creating them